# Updating AuthorID From ComboBOX value

Tags: java, sql, database, swing, jcombobox

I have the following sql tables:

Authors:

```
Id           Name

2         John Smith
```

Books:

```
Id        AuthorID       Title
 1           2          Shreak
```

I am trying to add more books to the books table through a GUI which has a drop down box to display the authors from the authors table and a textbox for entry of new book and a save button. The followiing is that correspond to the save button:

```
pprivate void save_bookActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    try {



        String sql = "INSERT into books (AuthorId,Title) VALUES (?,?)";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
       pst.setInt(1, author_name_combo.getSelectedItem());
        pst.setString(2, book_name.getText());


        pst.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New Book has been added");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}



private void FillCombo(){ 

    try {

    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Authors";
     pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
     rs = pst.executeQuery();
     while(rs.next()) {
         String author = rs.getString("Name");
         author_name_combo.addItem(author);  
     }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

I am a beginner and im struggling to populate the table with new data. the progamme compiles but the books table display NULL for Both AUTHOR ID and TITLE. how do I populate the table correctly so that author Id is automatically looked up from Authors table and given the approprate id number from there. please note author id is foreign key in books table.

Comment: Consider using a debugger or sprinkling your code with `System.out.println(someVariableThatYouWantToTestHere)` to see what is not working and where.

Comment: The problem is eventually in data type incompatibility. Plz show us your table definition.
Also to get the value of JCombobox use **getSelectedItem()**

Comment: getSelectedItem() is not compatible with setInt

Comment: please see edited code above, what would be inplace of getNAME() to correctly update the author id

Comment: @OuldAbba is correct. `getSelectedItem()` will get the selected Object held by the JComboBox's model. You then would call whatever method this object has to get the author ID int.

Comment: What *exactly* does the author_name_combo JComboBox hold? Numbers? Author objects? What?

Comment: ...Or you could just ignore the question...

Comment: combo box holds the name of authors authors table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're working with Swing (i.e. `JComboBox` and `JTextField`).

You are not assigning the values to the `?` variables correctly.  First, `AuthorID` is an integer and you need to assign the ID of the author, not the selected text.

One way to go around it is to create your own simple class to hold ID and name of an author, with the corresponding `toString()` method:

```
class OneAuthor extends AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, String> {
    public OneAuthor(Integer id, String name) {
        super(id, name);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getValue();
    }
}
```

Then, when you're populating your `JComboBox` with authors' names, use this class instead of String:

```
ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT id, name FROM authors ORDER BY name");

while(rs.next()) {
    author_names_combo.addItem(new OneAuthor(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2));
}
```

And then you can easily specify the correct author's ID:

```
pst.setInt(1, ((OneAuthor)author_name_combo.getSelectedItem()).getKey());
```

Second, instead of using `getSelectedText()`, you need to use `getText()` method on the book title text field.  `getSelectedText()` will only return the text highlighted in the field, while `getText()` will return the whole text.  Thus, your full code will be something like this:

```
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setInt(1, ((OneAuthor)author_name_combo.getSelectedItem()).getKey());
pst.setString(2, book_name.getText());
```

Comment: From his question tags, it appears that he is in fact using Swing and not AWT. You may wish to edit this answer to conform to this.

Comment: I am using Java Swing, the method seems complicated

Comment: @MuminAli give me a couple minutes, I'll update the answer for swing.  As for "complicated", well, this is the way to get your work done. It will be different in swing though.

Comment: thanks, is there no way of finding solution without using abstract map. I am required to limit the use of classes

Comment: would getSelectedIndex() of the combobox item and adding 1 cause problems? it does populate table correctly

Comment: @Mumin: that's a very fragile solution. It would only work if your author id were contiguous counting numbers, and they may be so now, but there's no guarantee that they will remain so in the future, and you don't want to put this artificial restriction on them. ID numbers are not really numbers at all as you would never use them do do mathematical calculations, but rather are unique identifiers that can easily be non-numeric.

Comment: i am struggling to correct it with your answer. i have edited and given the full code please tell me where to locate each of your statements.

Comment: @MuminAli You do need to add another class, as I indicated in my answer.  Then my next piece of code will go inside your `FillCombo` method - it's pretty obvious what/how needs to change.  Finally, change your `setString` methods on the prepared statement to the code I showed in my last block.

Answer (score 0):

If your `AuthorID` is of type `INTEGER` in your database then the problem is you are inserting `String` value for it in this statement `pst.setString(1, author_name_combo.getName());`

Comment: yes my authorid is actually INTEGER. i replaced setstring to setInt, but what would be in place of getName() ?

Comment: I want the same author id as in the author table ie the primary key

Comment: then first you need to get `AuthorID` from your `Author` table for that particular `Name` and use that `AuthodID` you get.

Comment: @Abu you need to be careful with this, as there (theoretically) be more than one author with the same name but different ID's.

Comment: @Aleks yeah I thought that same thing.